# What should I include in the GetCapabilities of a WFS to make it transactional

Tags: wfs-t, getcapabilities

I have created a (reversed engineered) WFS that I can load in QGIS. However I now want to make my WFS transactional.

QGIS however does not display the editing of my current WFS as an option, I guess this is because I need to indicate that my WFS is editable in the GetCapabilities.

I have been searching for examples on how I should indicate this in the GetCapabilities, but I wasn't able to find an example. Does anyone know what I should place in the GetCapabilities XML file to indicate that the WFS supports transactions? Or maybe give an example XML of a WFS that supports transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [OGC WFS 2.0 specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html) I think you need something like the following in the `<ows:OperationsMetadata>` section of the response.

```
...
<ows:Operation name="Transaction">
  <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
      <ows:Post xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://some-domain/cgi-bin/...PSI/ows?"/>
    </ows:HTTP>
  </ows:DCP>
  <ows:Parameter name="inputFormat">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
      <ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
      <ows:Value>OTHER MIME TYPES</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
  </ows:Parameter>
  <ows:Parameter name="vendorId">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
      <ows:Value>Any string that is used as a vendor identifier for the wfs:Native element.</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
  </ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
...
```

and a constraint set as:

```
<ows:Constraint name="ImplementsTransactionalWFS">
  <ows:NoValues/>
  <ows:DefaultValue>TRUE</ows:DefaultValue>
</ows:Constraint>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the specification - there is no need to "reverse engineer" an open specification

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found in a WFS GetCapabilities request with Transaction enabled.
Guess you need to include it in your API's GetCapabilities XML in the `<Request>` element.

```
 <Transaction>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get onlineResource="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/leo/wfs?request=Transaction"/>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Post onlineResource="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/leo/wfs"/>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
</Transaction>
```